# How do you modify the entry data before the template is rendered?

Tags: templating

I am using a pattern library which expects a different data structure to what is in `entry`. Is there a way to parse the `entry` through a transformer class before the template is rendered?

Currently I have created a Twig function to run: `{% set job = single(entry) %}` which returns the mapped data for each different entry type.

I would like to hook into Craft to do this before the template is rendered and remove any mapping logic from the templates. Is this possible/practical?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your use case a bit as to what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

Definitely possible; you'd need to write a plugin or module in PHP to do it though. Probably it could listen to for the `View::EVENT_BEGIN_PAGE` event, and get the injected element via `$element = Craft::$app->urlManager->getMatchedElement()`

Something sorta like this:

```php
use craft\web\View;

// ...

    $request = Craft::$app->getRequest();
    if ($request->getIsSiteRequest()) {
        // Handler: View::EVENT_BEGIN_PAGE
        Event::on(
            View::class,
            View::EVENT_BEGIN_PAGE,
            function () {
                Craft::debug(
                    'View::EVENT_BEGIN_PAGE',
                    __METHOD__
                );
                $element = Craft::$app->urlManager->getMatchedElement();
                if ($element !== null && ...) {
                    // ...do something
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

To make things clean, rather than modifying the element itself, I'd probably inject a new Twig variable, something like `entryTransformed` or something that your templating code could access.

Comment: Ok thanks this seems like a good idea. What would be the best way to add the variable inside the callback?

Comment: Yeah so the answer above isn't quite correct for what you're trying to do specifically. Check out my answer to that here: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/35427/add-variable-to-twig-context

Answer (score 2):

What format are you trying to get your data into?

I can think of a few different ways to handle this depending on what you might want to do:

## Element API

You don't mention what format you need but JSON is a popular format and the [Element API](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api) is a first party solution in Craft.

## Hidden Field

Another way to accomplish this would be to setup an [Incognito field](https://github.com/mmikkel/IncognitoField-Craft3) on your entry.  Then, listen to the `EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE_ELEMENT` event using a plugin to transform your data and save it to the format you need. This is similar to how you're doing it in Twig now, except just in a different "place" in the request.

This also has the advantage of doing the data transform once when the entry is saved (instead of every page load or messing around with `{% cache %}` tags). Then you just grab it in Twig like any other field, similar to how you're doing it now.

## Twig Filter

You mentioned this in your question. Since we don't have access to your Twig template, it's hard to know what you're trying to accomplish but I don't necessarily see a downside to doing it this way if your page performance is good. The only thing you might want to consider is adding {% cache %} tags around your output to give your server a break in that respect.

## Page Injection

See [Andrew's answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/35417/1016) if you need to do things even "higher up" before the template layer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I ended up going with Andrew's answer. Do you know a good method of adding a variable to the template context in the event in his example?

Comment: That's a good question, you might get more action if you ask it as  a new question but one way to do it would be to create a [Twig extension](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/extending-twig.html).