# Add variable to twig context

Tags: templating, frontend

I have created an event to transform the entry data before rendering the page so that it's ready to render components in the template.

```
Event::on(View::class, View::EVENT_BEGIN_PAGE, [$this, 'transformSingleEntry']);
```

Here's an example of what the function looks like. I've cut out most of the code, but essentially at the end of the function I have a `$transformed_entry` variable that I want to add to the twig context.

```
public function transformSingleEntry() {
  $entry = Craft::$app->urlManager->getMatchedElement();
  // ... do stuff
  $transformed_entry = [
    'title' => 'test',
    'url' => 'test',
  ];
  // Add $transformed_entry to the page context
}
```

I cannot find anything in the Craft documentation to help here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the way Twig works is that it populates a Twig Environment with a *context* of global variables.

Then any time a template `include`s another template, the context is passed down to it.

So if you want something to be globally available you have to insert it into the Twig environment *before* Twig is used, for it to be truly globally available.

You can do that via a Twig extension that `implements GlobalsInterface` like this:

https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-seomatic/blob/v3/src/twigextensions/SeomaticTwigExtension.php#L36

So you might need to revise how you're doing it actually, and instead of using `View::EVENT_BEGIN_PAGE` you can just do whatever you need to do inside your Twig extension.

Comment: Thanks that example helped a lot